# Should we make [ultimate-ninja-storm] tags clearer?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

At the moment, we have 4 tags for "Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm" series, which are:

- [ultimate-ninja-storm-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-2)
- [ultimate-ninja-storm-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-3)
- [ultimate-ninja-storm-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-4)
- [ultimate-ninja-storm-rev](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-rev)

They were created using the old 25 characters limit, so the title is incomplete. Should we add at least the Naruto part to make them clearer?
Something like:

- [naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2)
- [naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-3)
- [naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did the following:

[image: naruto tag renames]

- [ultimate-ninja-storm-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-2) → [naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2)
- [ultimate-ninja-storm-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-3) → [naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-3)
- [ultimate-ninja-storm-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-4) → [naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-4)
- [ultimate-ninja-storm-rev](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-rev) → [naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-rev](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-rev)

All the previous tags are now synonyms except for [ultimate-ninja-storm-rev](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-rev) which instead I made [ultimate-ninja-storm-revolution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-ninja-storm-revolution) a synonym for [naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-rev](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-rev) (couldn't fit in the word revolution for this last one unfortunately).

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am in favor.

I think adding the naruto part to the tag would be a meaningful improvement. People may not be aware that they need to omit the franchise name for this tag, so if they intend to make a question for Naruto Shippuden Ultimate Ninja Storm 2, they may end up inadvertendly making a new tag. Now that we have the room to add this franchise name, it could clarify things and make the site slightly more accessible.